# Gradle IntelliJ Idea JavaFX Runtime Error

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I wanted to use JavaFX to start doing an interface to my app but I get error:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/openjfx/gradle/JavaFXPlugin has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
> org/openjfx/gradle/JavaFXPlugin has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
```

Can someone please explain me how to fix it for IntelliJ Idea?

Thank you!

Comment: Gradle 5 requires Java 11 I think?

Answer (score 0):

It says that your current version of Java only recognises class file version up to 52.0. This means you have Java 1.8 (version 8) installed on your system. 
Simply install Java version 11 to remove the error. Or if you already have Java 11 installed, then check your project's JDK path and make sure that you've configured JDK 11.
 [Check this out for step by step solution on Eclipse IDE](https://crunchify.com/how-to-fix-java-lang-unsupportedclassversionerror-class-has-been-compiled-by-a-more-recent-version-of-the-java-runtime/)